# Deploying to AWS Elastic Beanstalk using AWS CodeBuild and EB CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codebuild

I'm trying to setup AWS Codebuild to deploy an application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

The problem is that it seems that the EB CLI is not available from AWS CodeBuild (It seems like it should, reading this... https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli-codebuild.html)

So when I specify an eb cli command on CodeBuild:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - echo Logging into Amazon ECR...
      - eb init --platform "multi-container-docker-18.03.1-ce-(generic)" --region us-west-1 application
```

I get:

```
/codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: eb: not found
```

I also tried installing the CLI with:

```
- pip install --upgrade awsebcli awscli
- eb init --platform "multi-container-docker-18.03.1-ce-(generic)" --region us-west-1 application
```

And extended the generated AWS CodeBuild role with full access to Elastic Beanstalk

But I get this error:

```
ERROR: NotAuthorizedError - Operation Denied. Access Denied
```

I added a `--debug` flag to the command, and this is the exact error:

```
2018-09-10 13:33:55,151 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : Making api call: (elasticbeanstalk, describe_configuration_settings) to region: us-west-1 with args:{'ApplicationName': 'application', 'EnvironmentName': 'staging'}
2018-09-10 13:33:55,495 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : Response: {'Error': {'Type': 'Sender', 'Code': 'InsufficientPrivilegesException', 'Message': 'Access Denied'}, 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '32f4e739-1694-4aa2-9e2e-076ec4861ae7', 'HTTPStatusCode': 403, 'date': 'Mon, 10 Sep 2018 13:33:55 GMT', 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
2018-09-10 13:33:55,495 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : API call finished, status = 403
```

Am I missing something? How can I use the EB CLI from CodeBuild properly?

Comment: At what point are you getting the `NotAuthorizedError`?

Comment: @progfan I'm getting the error after the call to `eb init`

Comment: Can you do `eb init --debug`? This will show a stack trace, but in the lines leading up to it, there should also be an indication of which API call failed. This will likely be the last debug log statement of the kind `Making api call: (<service name>, <operation>)`. You would likely need to give your user role permissions to that service + operation.

Comment: @progfan I added the debug flag and I can see a more precise error, I updated the question with the error. I can see that the "DescribeConfigurationSettings" endpoint is giving back a 403 status, but I already attached that policy to the service role (by giving full access).

Comment: Is there a chance this error could happen because the CodeBuild service and the beanstalk application are on different regions?

Comment: The policy is also configured to give access to all resources

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. They need to be in the same region, but that's probably not why you are getting the error. In your debug logs, is there an indication of which role the EBCLI is trying to use, because it's likely not the one you think it is.

Comment: I don't see any indication of which role it's using, but the codebuild project is configured with the expected role; I also see a successful API request before that one: `Making api call: (elasticbeanstalk, describe_environments) to region: us-west-1 with args:{'ApplicationName': application', 'IncludeDeleted': False}` which I believe is a protected endpoint as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179754/discussion-between-progfan-and-carlos-martinez).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out the EBCLI needs more than just the Elastic Beanstalk policy to work. That is why I was still getting an authentication error even though I attached a Full Access policy for Elastic Beanstalk.

What I did to understand the policies required was to create an IAM role with full access to all services, an attach it to the AWS CodeBuild project.

Then, going to `IAM Roles` -> `Role name` -> `Access advisor` you can check exactly what were the policies used by the project so you can create a proper Role for the service.

**Notes:**

- Recent activity usually appears within 4 hours. (It's likely that you won't see all the services being used in Access Advisor right away)
- You can start by using the **AWSElasticBeanstalkFullAccess** built-in policy instead of the **AdministratorAccess** policy to pinpoint what services are being used with the eb client